# Update Appbar after stream builder is done

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, stream-builder

After `stream builder` is done, it has the `numitems` as number of valid items. This `numitems` should show on a cart icon in `AppBar`. Right now the it is showing no number on cart icon as the UI is built before the stream builder is fully done.

The `stream builder` is inside the `body` widget as it also displays a list of items on the screen. Thats why I dont prefer to have`stream builder` within `AppBar`. I was wondering what is the suitable way to update `AppBar` with `numitems` after `stream builder` is finished.

Here is the code:

```dart
class BasketPage extends StatefulWidget {
    String title;
    UserAccount useraccount;
    BasketPage({required this.title, required this.useraccount});
    @override
    BasketPageState createState() {
      return BasketPageState(title: this.title, useraccount: this.useraccount);
    }
  }
  
  class BasketPageState extends State<BasketPage> {
  
    int numitems = 0;
    Stream<QuerySnapshot>? fooditemsStream;
    CollectionReference? fooditems;
  
    BasketPageState(){
      this.fooditems = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('fooditems');
      this.fooditemsStream = this.fooditems!
              .where("receiever", isEqualTo: this.useraccount.uname)
              .where("taken", isNull: true)
              .snapshots();
    }
  
    BasketBloc? basketBloc;
    List<FoodItem> foodItemsList = [];
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      basketBloc = BlocProvider.of<BasketBloc>(context);
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
      Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.shopping_cart_sharp,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                  this.numitems==0 // if numitems is 0 then return empty container else display numitems value
                      ? Container()
                      : Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 20.0,
                          width: 20.0,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "10",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 11.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),),),),],),),],),],),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
  
                children: <Widget>[
                  BlocListener<BasketBloc,BasketState>(
                    listener: (context,state){},
                    child: BlocBuilder<BasketBloc,BasketState>(
                        builder: (context,state) {
                          return Container();
                        }),),
  
  
                  Flexible(
                    child:
                     Column(
                       children: [
                         SizedBox(
                           child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: fooditemsStream,
                            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                      return Text('Something went wrong');
                                    }
  
                                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return Text("Loading");
                                    }
                                    if (snapshot.data!.docs.length == 0){
                                      return Text("Currently there are no food items in the list");
                                    }
                              // else return list and  update numitems when building list
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                ListView(
  
                                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                    Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
  
                                    final bool isExpired = data['expired'];
                                    if (isExpired) return Container();
                                    
                                    // update numitems here
                                    numitems= numitems+1; 
                                        return ListTile(
                                          contentPadding:const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom:5.0),
  
                                          title: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:8.0),
                                            child: Text(capitalize(data['item_name']),
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          ),                                  
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                ),],);},),),],)),],),),);}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just to add `setState()` after you update `numitems = numitems + 1`. This will make your whole `BasketPage` to rebuild.

But it's not the best solution, because your it causes your whole page to rebuild, when it is unnecessary. Better solution would be to use [ValueNotifier](https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-communication-between-widgets-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-b51ef627a58b). Wrap your `AppBar` with `ValueListenableBuilder` and create `ValueNotifier`.

As a side note you don't need to pass anything to your `BasketPageState`. If you need to access them use `widget.title`

Comment: Both of these suggestions are hepful and informative . When I try it right after `numitems= numitems+1;` , it shows this error "setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build" . I searched around and found it could resolved by adding your suggestion in postframe callback: `WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_){                                   basketItemsCountNotifier.value = numitems; }); `